# Display images using map() in react is not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase

I am trying to fetch images from Firebase storage and then display them in my react app.
Currently, there are 4 images in my storage and want to display all.

[image]

Fetch 4 different images from storage properly but displayed first image(1.png) 4 times.

```
useEffect(() => {
    const fetchImages = async () => {

    let result = await storageRef.child('images').listAll();
        let urlPromises = result.items.map(imageRef => imageRef.getDownloadURL());
    
        return Promise.all(urlPromises);
    }
    
    const loadImages = async () => {
        const urls = await fetchImages();
        setFiles(urls);
    }
    loadImages();
    }, []);
```

am I using map wrong?

```
 <div>
   {files.map((index) => (
      <img key={index} src={files} />
   ))}
 </div>
```

Comment: `<img key={index} src={index} />`, setting src to `files` incorrect

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should set each array element.

```
 <div>
   {files.map((file, index) => (
      <img key={'unique_key_string' + index} src={file} />
   ))}
 </div>
```

Comment: Oh! it's worked! Thank you so much. I made simple mistake.